# Can't reinstall node on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I was getting an error while working with Node.

Tried to do npm i for a project code downloaded from GitHub.
Got this error.

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\fs\lib\mkdir\index.js:1
$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7����%L]��%��∟�hk
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\fs\lib\index.js:5:10)
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Deleted NodeJS from Add/Delete Programs.
Tried to reinstall by downloading from official website.
Got this error.

Error while writing to file: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\is-core-module\package.json. Verify that you have access to that directory.

I'm stuck. Please help.

Comment: Post error messages as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove all node_modules and reinstall it
and try this https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm
should fix ur problem

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.